# how to handle the text entered from the keyboard pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, prompt

how to manage the text input from the keyboard using the command prompt in pl / sql Oracle.
I want to verified if the text inserted  is empty or insert more lines

-I use this line Address to retrieve a data from the keyboard

**set serveroutput on**

**accept my_var  varchar(256) prompt 'insert your Number:',**

Comment: This is not pl/sql.  This is sqlplus.  read the online docs on sqlplus.

Comment: but I want to use the Prompt clause in a plsql block (function or procedure) for a task

Comment: Put simply, you can't do that. PL/SQL provides no commands for interactive I/O. As @OldProgrammer has said, `ACCEPT` is a SQLPlus command, and that's the only place you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i know i sql plus is that you can prompt a user for a parameter value.. So that you let the user who is using sqlplus type in some text. I'm not sure if that's want you meant...

You can do this by adding a &.

So

Select person.name 
From person
Where age = &age